# msgpack-python failing to deserialize -> getting ExtraData error

Tags: python, mqtt, ros, msgpack

I'm trying to make MQTTtoROS Bridge work, and i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2627, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1407, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 923, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1206, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1799, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2275, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2461, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/home/animu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2615, in _handle_on_message
    t[1](self, self._userdata, message)
  File "/home/animu/catkin_ws/src/mqtt_bridge-master/src/mqtt_bridge/bridge.py", line 114, in _callback_mqtt
    ros_msg = self._create_ros_message(mqtt_msg)
  File "/home/animu/catkin_ws/src/mqtt_bridge-master/src/mqtt_bridge/bridge.py", line 124, in _create_ros_message
    msg_dict = self._deserialize(mqtt_msg.payload)
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 143, in msgpack._unpacker.unpackb (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:2143)
ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.
```

I can't find anything on it in the internet, as this bridge is i guess not commonly used. The only similar problems were in Salt and Kafka, but the solution is nowhere to be found. All python libraries are up to date, i double checked. The bridge sends messages from RoS to MQTT without any problems, both STR and BOOL types. Any message sent from MQTT ends up as this error with no reception from ROS.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late but I'll give some advice for future readers. 
First, make sure you have installed all requirements for the bridge to function. Check them by reading requirement.txt
Second, Edit mqtt_bridge configuration file to match topics from ROS and from your MQTT server. Also IP address/port of MQTT server.
Thats it.

Comment: A little bit late aswell, but I am experiencing the same issue as Animu described. You are saying to install all the requirements, but the requirements are all outdated. They don't work anymore. For example, it tells you to use bson, however it's outdated. So you install pymongo instead. The same goes for msgpack-python. It's deprecated so you have to install msgpack instead. It's still not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since Animu is a student, I assume that this was an assignment from his training or internship company. An answer is probably no use anymore, but since I also had this problem, I hereby offer a solution for future readers:

In the bridge repository there is a file called "demo_params.yaml". Or if you have already named it differently, then the .yaml file that contains your "settings".

This file includes the following:

```
mqtt:
  client:
    protocol: 4 # MQTTv311
  connection:
    host: localhost
    postage: 1883
    keepalive: 60
  private_path: device / 001
serializer: msgpack: dumps
deserializer: msgpack: loads
bridge:
  # ping pong
  - factory: mqtt_bridge.bridge: RosToMqttBridge
    msg_type: std_msgs.msg: Bool
    topic_from: / ping
    topic_to: ping
  - factory: mqtt_bridge.bridge: MqttToRosBridge
    msg_type: std_msgs.msg: Bool
    topic_from: ping
    topic_to: / pong
```

As you can see, it says msgpack is used to serialize and deserialize your messages that are sent back and forth. This mainly works for ROS to MQTT. The other way around, this does not work, as no correct actions are performed in the Python code. You have two solutions for this.

Continue to work with msgpack and make sure that the MQTT messages you publish are already encoded as msgpack would serialize them itself. (binary). This is a tricky solution, since you just want to keep MQTT messages human readable if you publish them manually. If you have written another program that publishes the MQTT messages, feel free to serialize the message first with msgpack and then publish. Then the bridge also works.

The other option is to have JSON serialization, instead of msgpack serialization. This is the default option of the bridge, but you can also specify this in your .yaml file. You do this by editing this:

```
serializer: msgpack: dumps
deserializer: msgpack: loads
```

to this:

```
serializer: json: dumps
deserializer: json: loads
```

Now you can publish mqtt messages both manually and with the help of software.
You do this as follows:

```
mosquitto_pub -t 'echo' -m '{"data": "test"}
```